# Azure Export SQL database example

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, azure-powershell, azure-sql-database

Given Microsoft is deprecating the previous method of exporting a SQL DB they have put up a suggested example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export-powershell):

```
$subscriptionId = "YOUR AZURE SUBSCRIPTION ID"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Database to export
$DatabaseName = "DATABASE-NAME"
$ResourceGroupName = "RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME"
$ServerName = "SERVER-NAME"
$serverAdmin = "ADMIN-NAME"
$serverPassword = "ADMIN-PASSWORD" 
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $serverPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $serverAdmin, $securePassword

# Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
$bacpacFilename = $DatabaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"

# Storage account info for the BACPAC
$BaseStorageUri = "https://STORAGE-NAME.blob.core.windows.net/BLOB-CONTAINER-NAME/"
$BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename
$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
$StorageKey = "YOUR STORAGE KEY"

$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
   -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
   -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
$exportRequest

# Check status of the export
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
```

I have filled in all the credentials as suggested in their example and I am getting this error:

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport : NotFound: Entity not found to invoke export
At C:\Users\bob\Desktop\DBBackupScript.ps1:47 char:18
+ ... rtRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $Resource ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.NewAzureSqlDatabaseExport
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: well, `entity not found` suggests you aren't picking an existing resource

Comment: Do you still having the same issue? Does my answer help to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell script example in your question above is tested working as expected for me.

However, I am not able to reproduce the same error message as yours even try to use non-existent resource group, database server or database.

**Important Note:**

1. For `$serverAdmin` and `$serverPassword`, their values should be single-quoted instead of double-quoted for the script to work
2. Check the version of your `AzureRm.Sql` module. Mine tested working is **2.5.0**
3. Try to use **-Debug** for your `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` command line to see the details

Comment: These helped. But the error msg I was seeing was from a typo in the database name. I had other issues and this helped with those. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that my answer has helped solving your problem

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the database name is case sensitive when using az sql db export. Correcting the casing on the database name and resource group solved this issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This has just come out from MS/Azure and helps greatly with DB Export.

https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/manage/azure-automation-automated-export

Answer (score 1):

Seems really stupid but the error for me was because my "DatabaseName" parameter was case sensitive.

I was sending in the value **"database"** but the actual database name was **"Database"**

seems crazy but might help someone out