# Error 404 when exporting SQL database in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

When I try to export my SQL database through the Azure Portal, I get a 404 error (Entity not found to invoke export).
[image: 404 error when trying to export database]

The weird thing is that a month ago it worked perfectly. I even wrote a little manual on how to do it as I exported it. A coworker found the issue when trying to do it herself.

I've seen [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46002891/385646) that "the database name is case sensitive when using az sql db export". It's strange, because we have not changed anything, but I've taken a look at the activity log of the DB and compared the log for the last successful export with the failing ones and I do see that the references to de DB in the JSON of the activity log have a different case (the last "B" of the database name):
[image: Different case in successful and error JSON]

I can also see that the database name appears with different case in different places. If I go to the Database itself, the last "B" is in uppercase, but if I go to the SQL Server, it is in lowercase. If I connect to the database from SSMS, it's lowercase too. I guess its correct name is with a lowercase b...

Anyway, I'm pretty sure we haven't changed it. In fact, in the "manual" I did a month ago I can see screenshots with the same case mismatch.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: what do you want to fix? just use proper name?

Comment: How? I go to the database in portal, click Export, fill everything, and it doesn't work... Shouldn't it just take the proper name if I do it through the interface?

Comment: we cant help you if the portal doesnt work, contact support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is happened in Azure backend, because we did nothing for the database.

We can not help you to fix the error. Only the Azure support can help you. According my experience, Azure  still have some bugs for now.

Ask Azure support like this in Portal, you can follow my example:

[image]

New support request:
[image]

Basics:

[image]

Azure will give some **Solutions** you can reference, just click next **Details**, give the more details or error screenshot for Azure.

[image]

Create the request, and wait the Azure support engineer contact you with Email or Phone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what I thought, but maybe I was missing something...