# Creating Sync Group timed out

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-sync

I'm trying to create a database sync between my on-premises database and an Azure database. I tried to create a Sync Group but after 1 hour of "Creating Sync Group" it timed out and canceled the creation. I've used Azure data sync multiple times and have a working Sync Agent. On none of my database I can create a new Data Sync Group. Does anyone know why I can't create a sync group?

I'm using a Pay-as-you-go subscription and the database is an Azure SQL Server database Standard S0: 10 DTUs

Error:
[Error after timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIIAI.png)

Comment: Can you show us the error message or any screenshots? Did you set the Azure database as Hub DB?

Comment: @LeonYue I added the error notification I got

Comment: I suggest you ask you Azure support  for help in Portal. We could not help you solve  the error with no more  details. I post my answer.If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I suggest you ask Azure support for help.

About How to create a new request to Azure support, please reference my answer of this blog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797585/10549281

Hope this helps.