# Export Azure Managed Instance Database backup to storage account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I am looking for an alternative to :

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport
```

For the purpose of taking Managed Instance Database backup and export it to storage account. The above command, I think supports only SQL Server.

Comment: You seem to be using azure managed database, what is the reason you look for alternative ? I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983010/azure-export-sql-database-example

Comment: this throws error that resource not found ```"Microsoft.sql/managedinstances/<servername>"```

since this command expects ```"Microsoft.sql/servers/<servername>"```

Comment: @NaMo If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark and vote up it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your're right, Powershell command doesn't support export the Azure SQL managed instance for now, you could reference this document:[Export to a BACPAC file using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-powershell):

[image]

Besides, the document also gives the other ways:

Exporting a BACPAC of a database from a managed instance using Azure PowerShell is not currently supported. Use SQL Server Management Studio or SQLPackage instead.

1. [Export to a BACPAC file using the SQLPackage utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-the-sqlpackage-utility)
2. [Export to a BACPAC file using SQL Server Management Studio
   (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

At least, you also can use T-SQL to backup the Azure SQL manage instance to Blob Storage:

First, you would need to store credentials that would be used to access Azure Blob Storage:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://myacc.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer] 
WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE' 
, SECRET = 'sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=GV0T9y%2B9%2F9%2FLEIipmuVee3jvYj4WpvBblo%3D&se=2019-06-01T00%2A%3AZ&sp=rwdl';
```

Once you create a credential, you can backup any database using standard BACKUP T-SQL command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE tpcc2501 
TO URL = 'https://myacc.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/tpcc2501.bak' 
WITH COPY_ONLY
```

Reference this Azure blog: [Native database backup in Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/native-database-backup-in-azure-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/386154).

Hope this helps.