How can I export Azure SQL Managed Instance database to Azure storage using a script?
I want export multiple TDE encrypted database of a SQL managed instance one by one to Azure's Storage. I can do operation using SSMS's GUI. But it will be time-consuming to do 100s of databases one-by-one by hand. Instead I want to do this using a script, if possible.
I cannot do this using T-SQL due to databases are TDE encrypted. So I cannot use the solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368759/2402577
For solution, ChatGPT directing me to use Start-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseExport in powershell.
Example:
# Select Azure Subscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "..."

# Define variables
$resourceGroup = "my-rg"
$instanceName = "my-prodmssql"
$databaseName = "AllotmentTest"
$storageAccountName = "alpertestbackup"
$containerName = "sql"
$bacpacName = "AllotmentTest.bacpac"

# Get storage account key
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -AccountName $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$secureStorageAccountKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $storageAccountKey -AsPlainText -Force

# Export database to BACPAC file in Azure Storage
Start-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
                                  -ManagedInstanceName $instanceName `
                                  -Name $databaseName `
                                  -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
                                  -StorageKey $secureStorageAccountKey `
                                  -StorageUri "https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$bacpacName"

I am getting following error message:
Start-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseExport : The term 'Start-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseExport' is not recognized as the name of a cmd
let, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
 the path is correct and try again.
At line:20 char:1
+ Start-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Start-AzSqlInstanceDatabaseExport:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Is there any way to achieve this issue using a script rather than using SSMS's GUI?

Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql#sqlpackage-utility SQLPackage is recommended.

We recommend the use of the SQLPackage utility for scale and performance in most production environments.

My only hope is using SQLPackage. But I was not able to find any example/tutorial related to SQLPackage usage regarding to this issue.

ChatGPT likes to invent cmdlets, libraries and classes that don't exist. The correct PowerShell cmdlet is New-AzSqlDatabaseExport.
This is for Azure SQL only
Here's an example of single database use:
# Variables
$resourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroup"
$serverName = "YourSqlServerName"
$databaseName = "YourDatabaseName"
$storageAccountName = "YourStorageAccountName"
$storageContainerName = "YourContainerName"
$bacpacFilename = "YourDatabase.bacpac"
$storageKey = "YourStorageAccountKey"

# Get the storage account context
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

# Export the database to a .bacpac file in the storage account
New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                        -ServerName $serverName `
                        -DatabaseName $databaseName `
                        -StorageKeytype "StorageAccessKey" `
                        -StorageKey $storageKey `
                        -StorageUri "$($storageContext.BlobEndPoint)$storageContainerName/$bacpacFilename"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseexport?view=azps-11.5.0
To do this for ALL databases, you'll need to list the database names in to an array and iterate through them, as per below.
# Variables
$resourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroup"
$serverName = "YourSqlServerName"
$storageAccountName = "YourStorageAccountName"
$storageContainerName = "YourContainerName"
$storageKey = "YourStorageAccountKey"

# Get the storage account context
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

# Get all database names from the SQL Server
$databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName

# Iterate through each database and export to .bacpac file
foreach ($db in $databases) {
    $databaseName = $db.DatabaseName
    $bacpacFilename = "$databaseName.bacpac"
    
    New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                            -ServerName $serverName `
                            -DatabaseName $databaseName `
                            -StorageKeytype "StorageAccessKey" `
                            -StorageKey $storageKey `
                            -StorageUri "$($storageContext.BlobEndPoint)$storageContainerName/$bacpacFilename"
    
    Write-Output "Exported $databaseName database to $bacpacFilename"
}


Sorry. The cmdlet is used is for Azure SQL only. I will post a new answer.

No worries sir. I feel like Azure makes it difficult as possible to perform this for MI through  a script.

@alper Are you using a service managed key for TDE, or customer managed using KeyVault?

I think service managed key which is enabled by default as I remember. How can I check this?

SELECT      CASE          WHEN [name] = 'HadrClusterType' THEN 'TDE Encryption Type'         ELSE [name]     END AS [Property],     [value] FROM sys.dm_operation_status WHERE [name] IN ('HadrClusterType', 'ServiceKeyName') If its INTERNAL it's SMK, if EXTERNAL it's CMK.

Its Service-managed key
